# Shopware 6: Extend existing core DAL entities with a reference

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to create a connection between 2 existing entities `PropertyGroup` and `CustomFieldSet`. Use-case is irrelevant.

So I created an `EntityExtension`:

```php
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('customFieldSet', 'custom_field_set', CustomFieldSetDefinition::class))
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return PropertyGroupDefinition::class;
    }
```

And override the administration component to also include this association when loading the entity:

```js
Component.override('sw-property-detail', {
    methods: {
        loadEntityData() {
            this.isLoading = true;
            const criteria = this.defaultCriteria;
            criteria.addAssociation('customFieldSet', new Criteria(1, 500));

            this.propertyRepository.get(this.groupId, Shopware.Context.api, criteria)
                .then((currentGroup) => {
                    this.propertyGroup = currentGroup;
                    this.isLoading = false;
                }).catch(() => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

(I tried to override `defaultCriteria` but that didn't work because of `this.$super` being unable to access computed properties).

But it keeps saying `FRAMEWORK__ASSOCIATION_NOT_FOUND`. I debugged the EntityDefinition and it seems that this extension is not even loaded.

I checked if my `EntityExtension` is loaded in the Symfony container and it is, but it seems that it doesn't reach the entity definition.

Comment: Did you tag the entity extensions with the `shopware.entity.extension` tag in the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EntityExtension` seems to be missing the addition of a `FkField` inside the function `extendFields`:

```php
public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
{
    $collection->add(
        (new FkField('custom_field_set', 'customFieldSetId', CustomFieldSetDefinition::class)),
    );
    $collection->add(
        (new ManyToOneAssociationField('customFieldSet', 'custom_field_set', CustomFieldSetDefinition::class))
    );
}
```

A new use statement has to be added for the `FkField`:

```php
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\FkField;
```